# Cant call subclass methods when using dynamic binding

Tags: c#

I have been trying to call a subclass method after creating an object of that subclass using dynamic binding.

For example two classes

```
public class Parent 


public class Child : Parent 

private void someMethod()....
```

I create object using dynamic binding

```
Parent person;

person = new Child(); //dynamic binding

person.someMethod(); //Does not work???
```

Why cant I call the method??

Comment: A. Your method is private. B. Your variable is of the type of the parent class which doesn't have that method so you'd have to cast to the child class

Comment: This is polymorphism not dynamic binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're confused by two paradigms and trying to put them in the code the same time.

1. Classic polymorphic approach:

   ```
   public class Parent
   {
       protected virtual void someMethod() {}
   }
   public class Child: Parent
   {
       protected override someMethod() {}
   }
   ...
   Parent person = new Child();
   person.someMethod(); // would cause compile-time error if someMethod is missed in Parent virtual table
   ```
2. C# dynamic code

   ```
   public class Parent {}

   public class Child : Parent 
   {
       private void someMethod() {}
   }
   ...
   dynamic person = new Child();
   person.someMethod(); // would cause run-time error if someMethod is absent at Child
   ```

So, your code is something in between them, apparently confusing the C# compiler.

Comment: Thanx for this!

Comment: I also tried cast i.e writing Child infront that worked also!

Comment: Side-note: Despite it's working OK, explicit casting is redundant here, and may lead to types misusage later if you change something. Just let compiler do it's job.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic binding works just fine:

```
dynamic person = new Child();
person.someMethod();
```

will compile and run just fine. Of course this is most of the time a bad idea, you are throwing down the drain all the type safety the language and the compiler provide but there are justified use cases.

Your scenario:

```
Person person = new Child();
person.someMethod();
```

Has nothing to do with dynamic binding, this is good old OO polymorphism. The reason it doesn't work is because `Person`
has absolutely no idea about `someMethod`. The compiler resolves calls at *compile time*, the fact the `person.GetType()` returns `Child` is a fact in *runtime*.